# How can I remove the home button in Vivaldi?

Tags: vivaldi

I have tried adding `.button-addressfield.home,.button-tabbar.home,.button-toolbar-small.home,.button-toolbar.home{display:none !important}` to the custom.css file, but it does not work. Is there another way I can remove or hide the home button?

Comment: Could you describe the whole procedure? Where is located the custom.css file that you've tried to change? Have you restarted Vi after each try?

Comment: Does this problem still persists? I use the `.button-toolbar.home {display:none}` rule successful (currently using version 1.13).

Answer (score 0):

It's been four years since you asked but now you can right click on the Home button, go to Customize, and remove it from the toolbar.